# LoadingController, Ionic2, Disappear automatically when using, dismissOnPageChange: true

Tags: ionic2

I am using loadingController Ionic2.

```
`fetchNotificationListAferUserDataget(){

this.loader = this._loadingController.create({
  content: "Please wait... Fetching online notifications",
  dismissOnPageChange:true
});
this.loader.present();  

this._userDataService.getNotificationList()
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.loader.dismiss();
      let status = data.status;
      let returnedData = data.json();
      console.log(status,returnedData)
      if(data.status == 200){

        if(returnedData.notifications.length > 0){
          this.notifications = returnedData.notifications;
          console.log(this.notifications);
          this.loader = this._loadingController.create({
            content: "Please wait... Fetching your purchased packages"
          });
          this.loader.present();
          this._userDataService.getAllPackageByUser(this.userData.user_id)
            .subscribe(
              (data) => this.populateUserPackages(data),
              (err) => this.showDataFetchErrorFromServer('Unable to fetch user packages')
            )
        }else if(returnedData.notifications.result == 0){
          console.log('no notifications found');
        }
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      this.showDataFetchErrorFromServer('Unable to fetch notifications')
    }
  );//end .subscribe
};`
```

But the problem I am facing is that loader appear and disappear automatically without my calling loader.dismiss();

Does anyone else facing same issue. Any solution for this.

**EDIT:** Full Function code included. loader dismiss immediately after **loader.present()**, without any error, but when I call **this.loader.dismiss();**, it gives me error because loader is already dismissed.

Comment: `dismissOnPageChange:true` it will implicitly call `dismiss` when moving to another page..

Comment: I am not moving to another page. It automatically dismiss just after this.loader.present(). On same page

Comment: are you getting errors?

Comment: Please see the EDIT in question

Comment: The second loader is dismissing immediately?

Comment: did you try with the option `dismissOnPageChange` set to false?

Comment: @AndreaRega, If I dont use dismissOnPageChange , everything works fine.

Comment: In which lifecycle event are you adding the loader?

Comment: @gerdi, Its not in any lifecycle event. It is in a custom function after ngInit, or as a matter of fact, any custom function, it has same behaviour.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @pabloim, there is no fix solution for this. But my problem was that I use 2 consecutive HTTP calls. I just add setTimeout on 2nd call. So first loader disappear , before 2nd appear. Please try that.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/8905), it is caused by triggering the `loader.present()` on the wrong life-cycle hook. I also had the same problem, where I had the loader loading on the `ionViewDidLoad()` hook. "The dom is not guaranteed to be ready in `ionViewDidLoad` and events are not guaranteed to be ready."

Try presenting the loader on the `ionViewDidEnter()` hook instead.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `setTimeout()` for this. Like:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.loader.dismiss();
}, 1000);
```

Also, please do not use the same variable `this.loader` for creating 2 loaders. Just use a local variable like `var loading = this._loadingController.create()`. This could create problems in Loading API. In ionic 2 documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/), it is mentioned:

> Note that after the component is dismissed, it will not be usable anymore and another one must be created. This can be avoided by wrapping the creation and presentation of the component in a reusable function as shown in the usage section below.

Comment: If I create loader in a function, how can I dismiss it from another function, like when ajax request finishes etc.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter and the same code of `setTimeout()` should work. Regardless, did this work?